# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onchange

I'm trying a simple (or so I thought) radio input change command. I have the script below which changes the class of a box when a certain radio button is selected but it keeps coming up with

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

I am using Wordpress and it works fine when it is in scripts.js but I need in in the page to put PHP within it.

```
$("#radio").on('change', 'input[type=radio]', (function() { 
  if ($("#port-filter-<?php echo ''.get_the_ID().''; ?>").is(":checked")) {
    $("#port-item-container").removeClass();
    $('#port-item-container').addClass('port-choice-<?php echo ''.get_the_ID().''; ?>');
  }
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `)})`, although you can just make it `})` if you remove the unneeded `(` before `function()`

Comment: you have to close one more "}"  at the end

Comment: I've tried another "}" and the same error occurs and I've tried "})" and a "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error shows.

Comment: @Tommy Note `)})`, not `})`

Comment: Remove "(" before function and add "});" at the end of the whole function block.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I tried: "although you can just make it }) if you remove the unneeded ( before function()" and it removed the error. Doesn't seem to be working now but it might be an issue with the code :/

Comment: It's working now. You were correct :)